# Two identical motherboards, same bios, one refuses to work with Zen 3 Ryzen

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

I have 2 MSI PRO VDH MAX B450 motherboards, both running the latest May 2021 BC BIOS

One works fine with every CPU I have, an Athlon 3000g, a 3300x, and a 5600x.

However, the second board refuses to POST with anything other than the Athlon, sitting at the CPU ezDebug light.

I've been building for a long time and I can't really think of any reason that this isn't working other than there's just some fault with the motherboard.

Everything is set up with a minimal build one stick of ram the usual and it just refuses to post.

Is there something that I'm forgetting about? Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm you have at least 7A38vBB on both motherboards?

Comment: @Ramhound I just disconnected the board for some other rounds of testing but I did just double check the BIOS 10 minutes ago and it was the June or July 2021 bios I think the last two numbers were c0 hold on I've got it on my USB stick let me pull it up on my laptop

Comment: `7A38vBC` is from May 2021.  It's not clear what version you have since none of the versions released by MSI have `C0` in them nor have any been released in June or July 2021.

Comment: @Ramhound It is the BC build so yeah over BB I just realized that I technically am using two different power supplies so I'm just stripping both machines apart and going to try to swap the power supply you know that makes no logical reason why it would work

Comment: @ramhound sorry apparently I can't count the c0 appears in the motherboard in fm fash and it was the 05 2021 bios it's been a long day so I confuse the 05 for June instead of May